# Can you set Tomcat’s access log directory dynamically?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat-valve

I am trying to know if it’s possible to have a per-month access log directory in Tomcat 7. After having read the [access log Valve documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve) it doesn’t seem like it.

Ideally, it would be something similar to this:

```
<Valve ...
    directory="logs/%d{YYYY-MM}/${tomcat.hostname}"
    ...
/>
```

Are there any variables that can be set to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do that with Tomcat. But if you use [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to rotate the logs, instead of letting Tomcat do it, then you have many more options.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but a possible workaround. I’m accepting it as there seems to be no way to configure `server.xml` in Tomcat to do what I want. Thanks.